# ionic responive table padding

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a table in my ionic application

```
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="item in topRow"> {{item}} </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="item in middleRow"> {{item}} </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="item in bottomRow"> {{item}} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and what I wanted was to add some padding to this table, I did this by, in my .css add

```
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

works great in my computer browser, but on a smaller screen, say a phone, `padding 15px` will make the table extend longer than the screen width (only half the table is visible on my phone, for example)

how can I add padding to my table, based on screen width, so that the table width is not bigger than the screen width?

I am able to get the screen width, using $window in my controller

```
$scope.window = {
    width: $window.screen.width,
    height: $window.screen.height
};
```

But how can I use this in my table?

EDIT: I got a great answer, but I feel it is too complicated (will use it unless there is a better (easier) way though)

My expected output is this:

[image: qwerty table]

A table, or grid or whatever could work, that displays the qwerty keyboard, the reason I needed the padding was because it just looked wrong with all characters pressed together.

Is there a better way of doing this maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
After reading the comments, I highly recommend using Bootstrap. With responsive tables. There is a good documentation at [W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_tables.asp). Too see how a responsive table works [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_table-responsive&stacked=h) and try to resize the window.

If you just want to add a padding based on screen width you can use the Javascript style attribute. You need to define a Id for the table or just use a class for the tds. After that all you need is something to make sure that the script is only fired if the screen is smaller than x.

Suggested Structure:

```
     <table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="item in topRow smallScreenPadding"> {{item}} </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="item in middleRow smallScreenPadding"> {{item}} </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="item in bottomRow smallScreenPadding"> {{item}} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now that we have the class, we only need some sweet JavaScript:

```
// Set Styles
function setStyle(){

  //get class Arrays
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("smallScreenPadding");

  // Check if Array exists and has at least 1 element
  if(typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem .length > 0){

    // Loop through array
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; ++i){

      // set style for current element.
      elem[i].style.padding = "your desired padding here e.g. 5px";

    }
  }
}


//Check for desired width and execute function (put in your own width check)
if (width <= x){
  setStyle();
}
```

If you don't want to use a Loop you can go for a CSSString (without a loop):

```
elem.style.cssText = cssString;
```

If you want to use only CSS you can try to use a CSS Framework, like Bootstrap. There you can use a responsive table which would make your work alot easier.

Regards, Megajin

Comment: I will try this for sure, thought it would be easier though (maybe this is 'easy'.. just not for me :P) Thanks for the fast reply

Comment: You're welcome. The easiest way would be the use of a CSS Framework. Don't be shy and ask if you need more help =).

Comment: could you take a look at my update? maybe you have some ideas

Comment: Do you want to show the keyboard like on a smartphone (e.g. start typing in a input box)? Or is the table displayed like a regular table in a site?

Comment: Just like a normal table, the image is actually my output with the provided table, and padding 15px (in my browser, on my phone only half the table is visible)

Comment: Ok, i recommend you use bootstrap. There is a nice documentation at W3S. I've also edited my answer.